# Have method opt out of class-level AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an `ApiController` class with 10 public methods in it.

Out of those 10 methods, nine require an `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]`. The one that doesn't, doesn't require any authorization.

If it weren't for that single method that doesn't require authorization, I would decorate the `ApiController` class with `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]`.

Instead of at the class level, I'm decorating all nine methods with the same `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` and not decorating that single method with an `[Authorize(...)]`.

What I don't like about this is that I have to repeat the same `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` nine times.

Is there a way that I can instead still decorate the class with `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]`, and only decorate the single method that shouldn't have `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` with an attribute that means something like "don't apply the class-level action filter for this specific method"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [[AllowAnonymous]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute. I've done this on the Login action when a website was in preview, for example, so anybody can see the Login page, but nobody can see the rest of the site until they login. It was a simple workaround for a client :-)

In fact I even wrote a custom attribute which read the setting from the database, so I could put the website into "lockdown", if you get what I mean.

Comment: So the `[AllowAnonymous]` on a method will supersede `[Authorize]` on the class, yes?

Comment: That's correct. See here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous